# Mysql Subquery to reverse order

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have this code and it is not working. I want to reverse the order after i make my query with the latest comments.

```
SELECT * 
FROM( 
    SELECT users.id, users.nome, users.email,users.foto, comments.content
    FROM users, comments 
    WHERE comments.posts_id=? AND comments.users_id=users.id
    ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 5) 
AS dummy 
ORDER BY comments.timecomment ASC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you just need to give your outer query something (cid) to sort on, then do what you're already doing;

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT users.id, users.nome, users.email,users.foto, 
             comments.content, comments.id cid
      FROM users, comments 
      WHERE comments.posts_id=1 AND comments.users_id=users.id
      ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 5) AS dummy
ORDER BY cid ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

The field you wish to sort on, `comments.timecomment`, does not seem to be selected in the inner SELECT query ...  Also, explicit reference to the table name may not be necessary in the outer query if the field name is unique.

How about:

```
SELECT * 
FROM( 
    SELECT users.id, users.nome, users.email,users.foto, comments.content,
    comments.timecomment
    FROM users, comments 
    WHERE comments.posts_id=? AND comments.users_id=users.id
    ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 5) 
AS dummy 
ORDER BY timecomment ASC
```

Comment: Ah - I've just updated my post. How about if you remove the table name in the outer query?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal just to output found comments reverse it in php:

```
SELECT users.id, users.nome, users.email,users.foto, comments.content
  FROM users, comments 
  WHERE comments.posts_id=? AND comments.users_id=users.id
  ORDER BY comments.id DESC LIMIT 5
```

$comments = array_reverse($comments);